# How to create a single smoother line on my scatter plot instead of multiple?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I create a single smoother on my scatter plot instead of multiple?

Here is what I'm using to plot the carat, price, and color of the diamonds data set.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price, color=factor(clarity))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth()
```

(I can't post pictures because I'm new to this site but here is the link to my result)

http://tinypic.com/r/2iw65bb/8

How can I get one smoother curve over all data, instead of one for each clarity, like it is giving me now? Also, I'd like to remove the standard error shading. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Put the coloring inside `geom_point()`. This results in the smoother being applied to the full data set while the separate coloring applies only to `geom_point()`. In general, when you want something to apply to all layers, put it inside the initial call to `ggplot`. When you want something to apply only to an individual layer (in this case coloring the points layer by clarity), put it inside that layer.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
       geom_point(aes(color=factor(clarity))) + stat_smooth()
```

To remove standard error shading:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + 
       geom_point(aes(color=factor(clarity))) + stat_smooth(se=FALSE)
```

Comment: you beat me by 2 seconds